# About using TypeScript on AWS NodeJS. (getting stacktrace of TS instead of JS one)

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, typescript

I am considering to convert my current js codebase to use TypeScript in NodeJS.

One thing that concern me is that if error occurs on a request, I can see the stacktrace in AWS CloudWatch (request log) to understand the exact code line that cause the problem.

If I use typescript, I suppose the log can still point me to the crash line from the transpiled js file. But I wonder if its possible to give me callstack to the ts file instead, which is more natural to me as I wrote ts instead of the js file.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript [can generate](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) source maps. Then it is simply a question of telling nodejs to use source maps in stack traces, [like so](https://github.com/evanw/node-source-map-support) for example.

Comment: The github project has not been updated for 7 months. Is it stopped update because of completeness or just abandoned...

Comment: Those both solutions are not maintained, anyone have a better solution instead of using `ts-node`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node which will transpile and execute your typescript code transparently, and will point to the original typescript files in stacktraces.